# PHPUnit + MVC testcases

Tags: php, testing, model-view-controller, phpunit

Today I tried to implement PHPUnit in my self developed MVC framework. When I try to run the test cases I wrote he always complains about the fact that he doesn't know the classes etc. So I tried to load a helper file with a bunch of includes and then it gave me a different error.

```
    Fatal error: Class 'MysqliDb' not found in /home/ansit-com/workspace/abrechnung/mvc/model/Model.php on line 7
```

This is located in the database.php class.

The code of my helper file looks like this.

```
 <?php 
include('controllers/Controller.php'); 
include('model/Model.php');
include('view/view_class.php');
include('view/libs/Smarty.class.php');
include('configs/config.inc.php');
include('libs/database.php');
include('libs/PrefixCache.php');
include('libs/helper.php');
include('libs/language.php');
include('libs/decimal_mark.php');
include('libs/validation.php');
include ('libs/permissionCheck.php');
include('theme/configs/constant.php');
?>
```

I already tried to change the pathname, I have the following structure:
    projectname/controllers
    projectname/models
    projectname/tests (file where my helper and all tests are located)

Structure of my program https://i.stack.imgur.com/omyAA.jpg

This is the very first time I work with unit testing, on the internet I only find examples of how to do it in existing frameworks.
Please let me know if I forgot to mention something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem.
I changed all my paths to absolute paths. Changed all the includes to include_once because I redeclared certain classes and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `phpunit.xml` file in the project root? If so, you can specify a `bootstrap` attribute in the `phpunit` element which you can set with your helper file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.6/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="ProjectTestSuite">
            <!-- List the folder(s) in which your tests are, here -->
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests</directory>

        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

With this file, you can run `phpunit` from your project root, and it automatically fetches the settings from the `phpunit.xml` file.

Also have a look at https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.phpunit for more configuration options.

Comment: I tried to do this but I still get the same error, at least when I try to run straight from my terminal. When I try to run it with eclipse MakeGood the console tels me `Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found in /home/users/Schreibtisch/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510/resources/php/vendor/piece/stagehand-testrunner/src/DependencyInjection/PHPUnitConfigurationFactory.php on line 70`
I already had this error and could then solve it by adding `require '/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';` but if I do this now it does nothing

Comment: I have the feeling that the include_paths in your project are not set up correctly. Could you insert a `echo get_include_path(); exit` somewhere in the code before the errors are thrown? There should be at least `.:`. Either way, you could try to insert the line `set_include_path(__DIR__ . ':' . get_include_path()`, perhaps this will help. Then you should be able to include PHP files with `include 'relative/path/from/current/dir/file.php`.

Comment: The reply I get here is `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear` 
I don't really know what to make out of that. That's far from where the helper.php or my workspace are located

Comment: The Dot stands for "current directory" - so normally you should be able to specify a relative path and it should be found in one of these locations. `include 'controller/Controller.php'` would then be searched in `/path/to/helperfile.php/controller/Controller.php`, `/usr/share/php/controller/Controller.php` and `/usr/share/pear/controller/Controller.php`.

Comment: Could you update your OP with the file structure of your project, please? With absolute paths to your project dir and in it where your helper file and the to-be-included files are located?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with OP but I posted a picture of my file structure in my original message.

Comment: Just made some progress, when I give the absolute path it does seem to find the classes. Now he complains that he can't find the link to the classes extended in those classes. I have the feeling I'm doing something terribly wrong here.